# nav-collapse button not showing when resizing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am quite new on making a website with bootstrap. 
My website has a fixed navbar

```
    <div class="navbar-wrapper">
  <!-- Wrap the .navbar in .container to center it within the absolutely positioned parent. -->
  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
      <!-- Responsive Navbar Part 1: Button for triggering responsive navbar (not covered in tutorial). Include responsive CSS to utilize. -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="#" class="brand" title="websitename">&nbsp;</a>
```

This is all going perfect in my browser. But when I resize the browser to a smaller size (instead of full size) the brandlogo is moving to much to the left and half of it dissapears on the leftside. The button (btn-navbar) is to much to the right, so its behind the scrollbar.

How can I fix this in the css? Do I need to add css to @media?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/
This will help you fix your problem :-)
Hope this helps!

make sure you have all of your CSS and JS in place correctly...